# Using database model (keys) to reference runtime objects, good or bad idea?

Tags: c++, reference, coding-style, relational-database, idioms

In my previous job, program processing relied on data stored in a database. So the database model leads the runtime program's data structures. Thus it is convenient to use primary key values as reference to other objects. For example :

1. Considering a company sells books via internet we have classes `Book`, `Order` and `Customer`.

   - `Book` class contains different properties about the book and a unique identifier such as ISBN.
   - `Customer` class contains all data (and much more) the company needs to ship books to customers, such as email address. Customer objects have also a unique persistent id that identify them.
   - Thus the `Order` class contains two relational references `int isbn;` (the book id) and `int customer_id;`.

   In this example, order class methods do not need to access customer data or book data, so order class doesn't need to depend on them.
2. Now consider another class to write and send the email confirmation of an order :

   ```
   class OrderMailer
   {
      // Customer index
      std::map<int, Customer *> customers;
   ...
      // we have a function that sends email with low level parameters
      void sendEmail(const std::string& mailAddress, const std::string& body);

      // and we have another method that simply sends the email for a given order
      void sendEmail(const Order& order);
   };
   ```

   `sendEmail(const Order& order)` method will need the customer's email address, thus it will need to get the object from its identifier. That's why we have a map, so the address will be accessed like :

   ```
   const std::string& target = customers[order.customer_id]->emailAddress; // not found test omitted for reading.
   ```

I used this way of referencing without questioning because object/record id's are the way to identify objects throughout the company (code, logs, discussion with other IT's). Runtime data structures always reflected the database model. May not be a solid argument but was very helpful switching between database world and runtime world (C++, Python, JavaScript).

I'm not with that company anymore but kept this way of programming when dealing with persistent records. I'm not sure it's right to use a logical way of referencing objects instead of those provided by language (pointers or C++ references). It sounds really bad to me when said like that.

- Pros :

  - Runtime data structures reflect the underlying relational data model (easier to understand).
  - Avoids useless coupling of classes (in example, `Order` does not depend on `Customer` and `Book` classes).
  - Unique identifiers can be strings that are human friendly to read.
- Cons :

  - Not using fundamental features of the language (pointers and references) to do this sounds like bad practice.
  - The need for dictionaries/index (maps) to access data of logically referenced objects.

I'm not sure it is a good thing to do. Are there rules to decide whether to- or not to use this approach?

Comment: Wouldn't the second `sendEmail` overload take an `order_id` parameter, from which it infers the order — something like: `Order& order = *orders[order_id];`?

Comment: Another pro for this idea is that objects representing database facts could be very short-lived (managed via locally scoped smart pointers), thus allowing the underlying persistence mechanisms to persist updates quite eagerly.

Comment: Yes it could be like that, but when writing the example I assumed that the OrderMailer class used directly instances of Orders. the reason is that OrderMail need to access Order (public) members. I will correct it if you think this make the example easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr: Use pointers and references whenever they organically make sense in your program.**

The design rationale for database table records is different than for classes used in programming.

- A (relational) database is structured as tables; the entities  used in a program - aren't; at least, not generally.
- DB tables typically wish to follow principles such as "normal forms".
- Databases are accessed using *declarative* queries, not programs. Behind the scenes, what actually gets computed by the DB management system may be different (e.g. involve indices rather than work on multiple key fields). In fact, the database might even be *columnar*, in which case you don't even hold individual records, e.g. the titles of all books in sequence.

In a program,

- You often want to refer to "that object I was just working with".
- You sometime only want part of the information identifying a single DB table record; or *more* than what identifies a single table record; or computed data or information that's not even in the DB to begin with.
- (C++-specific) there are mechanisms such as inheritance and templating, which a relational DB does not admit

So, in principle, you can't assume that the choice of classes in your program should be identical to that in your database. Nor is it always reasonable to identify entities by their DB key fields.

The latter choice may also have a negative impact on performance, as you yourself mentioned: If you have a container of Book-class objects in memory, and some other data structure refers to them using ISBN's, you would need to perform an ISBN-search in that container on every access. This, instead of using a pointer, or retrieving the partial book data you need, once, without having to follow references later.  (Of course, this is a problem only if this lookup-by-ISBN occurs a very large number of times; don't bother to optimize the performance of code which runs rarely.)

About your Pros and Cons:

> Pros :
>
> - If there is an underlying relational data model, the runtime data
>   structures reflect the data model and things are easier to understand

A relational data model is not "underlying" - unless you're writing classes merely for reading and writing from the DB. Also, the what the DB is physically stored in the DBMS' memory doesn't necessarily reflect the relational structure.

> - This avoid useless coupling of classes (In the example, Order does not depends on Customer and Book classes)

1. Your example shows the coupling is often not useless, but appropriate. Defining order of books probably needs to know what a book is and what a customer is.
2. One can avoid coupling with pointers and references as well, using [forward declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/forward-declaration/info):

   ```
   class Book;
   class Customer;

   class Order {
       // ...

       const Book& book; // assuming there's just one book per order here
       const Customer& customer;

       // ...
   }
   ```

> - Unique identifiers can be strings that are very human friendly to read

When you read a program, you don't read any of those strings, you will only read `std::string book_title;` as a class member, and that's no easier to read than `const Book& related_book`.

> Cons :
>
> - Why not using the basic fundamental features of the language that are pointers and references to do this? thats sounds a bad approach.

Use language constructs when they organically make sense in your program. Sometimes it makes sense to use other structures (e.g. indices in an array). Case-by-case basis.

> - We need to use dictionaries/index (maps) every-time we want to access data of logically referenced objects

Indeed.

Answer (score -1):

Well this is how I would do it. Since this is C++ and if we use standard containers. Why not use iterators. I added some printing code for easy testing also.

If you want iterator stability change the vector to a list. For better lookup operations have a look at `boost::multi_index` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html. `boost::multi_index` is also good to use if iterator stability is important.

It would probably also be easy to use `boost::serialization` if you want to write your data structures to file.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Streamable
{
  virtual ~Streamable() = default;
  virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream& ost) const = 0;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Streamable& str)
{
  return str.print(ost);
}

struct Customer : public Streamable
{
  std::string name_m;
  Customer(const std::string& name_):name_m(name_)
  {}
  std::ostream& print(std::ostream& ost) const
  {
    return ost<<name_m;
  }
};

struct CustomerColl : public std::vector<Customer>,
              public Streamable
{
  CustomerColl(std::initializer_list<Customer> customers)
    :std::vector<Customer>(customers)
  {}
  std::ostream& print(std::ostream& ost) const
  {
    ost<<"Customers:"<<std::endl;
    for(const auto& c: *this)
    {
      ost<<c<<std::endl;
    }
    return ost;
  }
};

struct Book : public Streamable
{
  std::string title_m;
  unsigned int isbn_m;

  Book(const std::string& title_, const unsigned int& isbn_)
    :title_m(title_),isbn_m(isbn_)
  {}
  std::ostream& print(std::ostream& ost) const
  {
    return ost<<title_m<<":{"<<isbn_m<<"}";
  }
};

struct BookColl : public std::vector<Book>,
          public Streamable
{
  BookColl(std::initializer_list<Book> books)
    :std::vector<Book>(books)
  {}
  std::ostream& print(std::ostream& ost) const
  {
    ost<<"Books:"<<std::endl;
    for(const auto& b: *this)
    {
      ost<<b<<std::endl;
    }
    return ost;
  }
};

struct Order : public Streamable
{
  BookColl::const_iterator book_m;
  CustomerColl::const_iterator customer_m;

  Order(const BookColl::const_iterator& book_,
    const CustomerColl::const_iterator& customer_)
    :book_m(book_),customer_m(customer_)
  {}
  std::ostream& print(std::ostream& ost) const
  {
    return ost<<"["<<*customer_m<<"->"<<*book_m<<"]";
  }
};

struct OrderColl : public std::vector<Order>,
           public Streamable
{
  OrderColl(std::initializer_list<Order> orders)
    :std::vector<Order>(orders)
  {}
  std::ostream& print(std::ostream& ost) const
  {
    ost<<"Orders:"<<std::endl;
    for(const auto& o: *this)
    {
      ost<<o<<std::endl;
    }
    return ost;
  }
};

int main()
{
  CustomerColl customers{{"Anna"},{"David"},{"Lisa"}};
  BookColl books{{"C++",123},{"Java",234},{"Lisp",345}};

  OrderColl orders{{books.begin(),customers.begin()},{books.begin(),customers.begin()+1},{books.end()-1,customers.begin()+2}};

  std::cout<<customers<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<books<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<orders<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is interesting but you didn't clearly answered the question (good? bad idea?). Also, I'm not sure this solve the problem : if I understand what you do, you consider that Objects that are referenced by identifier are members of an abstract collection. Thus you can reference your objects with iterators (right?). Ok, but there is not rule to convert iterators to keys (they are not consecutive integers for example, and more important : they are not created by the runtime program (eg : isbn number)). So in your solution you make the reference at runtime when instantiating orders.

Comment: OK, if you need some globally unique logical ID for all objects across multiple environments I guess you need to have unique ID for that. But then that is an external requirement, if you keep within a single program I would advice against adding extra IDs to your classes as they, as you said can be identified with pointers/iterators. In either case I would still suggest looking at `boost::multi_index` it is a very powerful tool. I think my point is that you should not invent your own pointers if there is not external need for it. And why do you need to convert iterators to keys?

Comment: Sorry, for loading data we need to convert key to iterators.

Comment: If you read `Book`s and `Customer`s from file/external DB into containers where you can search for the relevant IDs, e.g. using `boost::multi_index` you can use those iterators in your `Order` class. I would prefer this since you only need to do two slower searches to build your `Order` then you can use fast direct access with the iterators, this is under the assumption that the `Order` object will be referenced more times then the times we need to create them. Or am I still missing something?

Comment: ok, I've just been reading the documentation of `boost::multi_index` its a very flexible way to reflect relational model and it's data much more powerful than maps (I carefully chosen primary keys with just one index in order to avoid focusing on multi index primary keys) but that still is a kind of map. So your answer would be : yes its a good idea to map relational model into runtime structure. Thanks for your answers and comments, i ll leave the question opened since I really want to have multiple opinions on the subject.